# How to print posts and tags associated?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my database schema:

```
Post:
id
title
body
date

Tag:
id
title

Post_Tag:
id
id_post
id_tag

Comment:
id
id_post
body
date
```

There is a many to many relationship between post and tag.

I need to print in homepage this for the latest 10 posts:

```
<a href="post.php?id=ID_POST">POST_TITLE</a>

POST_BODY

<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_1"> TAG_TITLE_1 </a>
<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_2"> TAG_TITLE_2 </a>
<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_3"> TAG_TITLE_3 </a>

COMMENTS_NUMBER
```

I write this query but it is a little complicated to extract tags in php for each post:

```
SELECT p.title, p.id, p.date, t.title, t.id, COUNT(c.id)
             FROM post p
             LEFT JOIN post_tag pt 
             ON p.id=pt.id_post
             LEFT JOIN tag t 
             ON t.id=pt.id_tag
             LEFT JOIN comment c
             ON p.id=c.id_post
             GROUP BY p.title, p.id, p.date, t.title
             ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: @FAngel More like "definite  duplicate".

Answer (score 0):

1.There is no need to use so many columns in GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY p.id
```

will work - you will get number of comments for the corresponding post.

2.As you are selecting 10 posts, add LIMIT to the query:

```
LIMIT 0,10
```